# Data lost between Socket.Send and Socket.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, network-programming, data-loss

I have a client-server application that I recently modified to keep BeginRecieve being called another time on the same Socket before the first one finishes. Now the first message is received perfectly, but on the next one the buffer for the header (see code below) is filled with big fat zeroes instead of the data I'm supposed to be receiving.

```
public class Client
    {
    Socket sock;
    Message message;
    MessageHeader header;
    byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE];
    byte[] dataBuffer;

    bool activeReceiver = false;

    public delegate void DisconnectedHandler(Client c);
    public event DisconnectedHandler Disconnected;

    public delegate void DataReceivedHandler(Client c, Message m);
    public event DataReceivedHandler DataReceived;

    public Client(Socket sock)
        {
        this.sock = sock;
        sock.BeginReceive(headerBuffer, 0, MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
        }

    internal void Activate()
        {
        activeReceiver = true;
        sock.BeginReceive(headerBuffer, 0, MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
        }

    internal void ForceReceive()
        {
        if (!activeReceiver)
            {
            sock.BeginReceive(headerBuffer, 0, MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
            }
        }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
        int received;
        try
            {
            received = sock.EndReceive(result);
            if (received != MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE && Disconnected != null)
                {
                Disconnected(this);
                return;
                }
                else if (received == MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE)
                {
                header = new MessageHeader(headerBuffer);

                if (header.size > 0)
                    {
                    dataBuffer = new byte[header.size];
                    sock.Receive(dataBuffer);
                    message = new Message(header, dataBuffer);
                    if (DataReceived != null)
                        {
                        DataReceived(this, message);
                        }
                    }

                message = null;
                headerBuffer = new byte[MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE];
                dataBuffer = null;
                if (sock != null && activeReceiver)
                    {
                    sock.BeginReceive(headerBuffer, 0, MessageHeader.HEADER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (SocketException sex)
            {
            switch (sex.SocketErrorCode)
                {
                case SocketError.ConnectionAborted:
                case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                    if (Disconnected != null)
                        {
                        Disconnected(this);
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And MessageHeader is a simple little class:

```
public class MessageHeader
    {
    public static int HEADER_SIZE = 12;
    public int type, size, source;

    public MessageHeader(int type, int size, int source)
        {
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;
        this.source = source;
        }

    public MessageHeader(byte[] raw)
        {
        if (raw.Length != HEADER_SIZE)
            {
            type = -1;
            size = -1;
            source = -1;
            }

        type = BitConverter.ToInt32(raw, 0);
        size = BitConverter.ToInt32(raw, 4);
        source = BitConverter.ToInt32(raw, 8);
        }

    public byte[] toBytes()
        {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];
        BitConverter.GetBytes(type).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(size).CopyTo(bytes, 4);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(source).CopyTo(bytes, 8);
        return bytes;
        }
    }
```

The way this used to work (and it worked flawlessly) was activeReceiver wasn't a thing, BeginReceive would be called at the end of every callback. Now the new modification is the activeReceiver variable along with the ForceReceive and Activate methods. Until it's safe to put the Client back into the mode where BeginReceive is automatically called, ForceReceive() is called on it from the outside after the data is processed by the DataReceived delegate. When it becomes safe to reenter the original behavior, Activate is called instead of ForceReceive and from then on it's back to the original behavior. In my only possible test case here this stage is never reached. There is 1 exchange of messages between the server and the client that goes well, then the client locks up when the server doesn't respond to the next message.

Note that when I get the 0-es (which is the 2nd message from the client overall) we do enter the case where the correct number of bytes is received in the headerBuffer, only all 12 of those are 0-es.

UPDATE: So I worked around it with a really ham handed solution that is wasteful in terms of memory, but would like to do a more elegant and more memory efficent solution, so if anybody figures this out, I'd still be happy to see this mystery solved.

Comment: my advice here; add lots of trace output - in particular, I'm very concerned that this code doesn't handle fragmentation *at all* - there are **no** guarantees whatsoever that you're going to receive exactly a header and then exactly a payload, even if you get the buffer sizes right - **any** arrangement of positive receive sizes is valid - including getting 1 byte per [begin]receive[async]. So: I'd trace "issuing BeginReceive, buffer is {buffer.Length} bytes", "EndReceive, got {received} bytes", etc; in particular, you don't even *try* to process the result from `sock.Receive(dataBuffer);`

Comment: side note: endianness is a thing; at the moment, your code is CPU-endian; that'll **mostly work**, but if this code needs to work on anything other than known hardware, it is better to explicitly code to specific endianness. Besides which, `BitConverter` is just not friendly :)

Comment: I'll fix the packet size thing, it's like this because I was under the impression that the C# library handled the finikier nature of dealing with low level TCP and sends and receives would match at the higher level. For now I'm not all that worried about endianness, I mean, correct me if I'm wrong, but targeting Windows and x86 only should take care of that.

Comment: If you're *only* targeting x86 on Windows, then yes: it'll work reliably

Comment: This issue isn't caused by the data size though, what could have happened is that I didn't get all the data from the data portion of the first message, and somehow 12 0-es were in line to be received, but I get all the data. I'll take care of the 1 receive per 1 send problem anyway, but unfortunately it's not the thing causing the problem.